# Calling startActivity() from outside of an activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android

I am trying to start an activity inside a service class. I have a following code:

```
public class SendLinkService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bundle.getString("URL"));
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

It gives exception on following line of onStartCommand() :

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: "I am trying to start an activity inside a service class" -- why does this service even exist? What value is this code adding by being in a service, rather than being in an activity?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bundle.getString("URL"));
Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```

Comment: For `(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) && (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)` it is mandatory to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` while calling `startActivity()` from outside of an `Activity` context.

Docs - https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes#fant-required

Answer (score 6):

@hariharan answer works. However it also work without setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the first case. More accurate answer is:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bundle.getString("URL"));
Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

For `(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) || (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)` it is mandatory to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` while calling `startActivity()` from outside of an `Activity` context.

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes#fant-required)

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bundle.getString("URL"));
Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```